# How to monitor a Java program using Jconsole?

Tags: java, multithreading, jconsole

I have written a program to print number from 1 to 200 using 2 threads.

Now I want to monitor this program using JConsole.

Basically I want to learn how to use JConsole for monitoring an application.

I searched google but couldn't find something useful.

How I can achieve this?

When I started `jconsole.exe` in bin folder.  It asks for hostname and port number. 
Here in my case, there is none, I guess.
Can somebody guide.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to enable `JMX` by adding the following `JVM` arguments :

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8484
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

These parameters will allow any `JMX` monitoring tool to access and monitoring your application.

Also i suggest you to use [`visualVM`](https://visualvm.github.io/) its more powerful tool.
some features for `visualVM`:

- Provide a CPU profiling.
- Provide all info about Threads.
- Provide the JVM Heap and the memory states.
- Provide Info about the GC activities.

Comment: Where should I add these lines?

Comment: If your using `Eclipse IDE`, then `Right click on your project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings -> Select your launcher class -> Arguments tap`

Comment: Start you application, the start `jconsole`, and you'll find a you app process.

Comment: Welcome, and please don't forget to accept it as answer if that solve your problem :).

Answer (score 10):

Let's say you have a class `Test` under package `p1` where you have the code to print numbers from 1 to 200 using 2 threads(which you want to monitor).

So to use **[jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)** for monitoring your application, you would need to compile and execute your code first and while your code is executing...

- **`Start` -> `Run` -> `jconsole.exe` and hit/press `Enter`**

  [image]
- **Select the application which you want to monitor and then click `Connect`.**

  [image]

Alternatively,you can use **[VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)** for this purpose as well.

- [image]

Answer (score 1):

JConsole find all the running application at the time of JConsole start-up. Then only the currently running applications port and host will be displayed in the list. So first you need to start the application then start the JConsole.