# How to add my application in jConsole local process?

Tags: java, jconsole

I developed a Java application with the project name DMS. Now I want to judge the performance of the application by using jConsole. When i open the jConsole.exe frm jdk_installation/bin package i am unable to see my application name in the local process list excepting showing only one process sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole . Please provide any sugession to resolve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass on the [following](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) system arguments when starting JVM:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10200
```

Comment: I already did this from the reading - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280229/how-to-monitor-a-java-program-using-jconsole.  I add this inside VM arguments, under arguments tab.

Comment: Then what's the issue? Is your application runnning when you open jconsole? or if you dont see in jconsole, try manuall selecting remote process radio button, in textbox type localhost:10200 and click on connect

Comment: In remote process it also asking for Username & password

Comment: No keep it blank. See that we said no authentication with parameter `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false`

Comment: I filles localhost:8080 for the process (running locally on my machine), but giving the message - Connection failed: error during JRMP connection; nested exception is : java.io.EOFException

Comment: how are you running it? Are you running a standalone program or something else?

Comment: I running my application via tomcat (eclipse, Open jsp -> run -> run on server) & up the application in browser (link - http://localhost:8080/DMS/ietmLoginDialog.jsp)

Comment: 8080 is a web port in your case and not JMX port. I would suggest you read it online and close this question.

Comment: Great @user3916928. Glad it worked for you. Can you please close this question along with solution so it would help someone in future please?