# Can jconsole be used to monitor live applications - applications deployed in prode

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

Jconsole can be used to monitor local process and remote process. Can live applications be monitored using jconsole.

Comment: Refer to this other question already answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280229/how-to-monitor-a-java-program-using-jconsole

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor a Java program using Jconsole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280229/how-to-monitor-a-java-program-using-jconsole)

Comment: V_singh The question you asked me to refer is simply monitoring a Java process running in our machine. My question here is how to monitor live applications (application deployed in production).

Answer (score 1):

By monitoring live applications, I believe you meant applications currently running in production. Attaching local jconsole to production application is never recommended as it will have a lot of performance impact. However remote jconsole to a production application is fine with little performance impact.

A good read from Oracle can be found here on the same topic.
https://community.oracle.com/blogs/emcmanus/2006/07/21/how-much-does-it-cost-monitor-app-jconsole